# How to check input in Textbox Tkinter Python?

Tags: python, tkinter

I am Python coder and got stuck in a question that "How to check input in textbox of tkinter python". The problem is that it is not giving output on writing this code .

```
def start(event):
    a = main.get(1.0,END)
    if a == 'ver':
        print('.....')

main = Text(root)
main.pack()
root.bind('<Return>',start)
```

Answer (score 0):

We can do this by `get()` method:

```
from tkinter import *
a=Tk()
def check():
    print(x.get('1.0',END)[:-1])
x=Text(a)
b=Button(a,text='Check',command=check)
x.pack()
b.pack()
a.mainloop()
```

Answer (score 0):

The text widget guarantees that there is always a trailing newline. When you do `get(1.0,END)` you're getting that trailing newline even if the user doesn't enter a newline.

If you want to get exactly what the user entered, use `get("1.0", "end-1c")`. That will get all of the characters up to the end, minus one character.

Note: text indexes are strings of the form *line.character*. Your code is using the floating point value `1.0` which is incorrect. It works fine in some cases, but it won't work in all. You should always use a string rather than a float for text indexes.

Answer (score 0):

```
from tkinter import *
from threading import Thread

root = Tk()

def check():
    while True :
        a = main.get(1.0,END)[:-1]
        if a == 'ver':
            print('.....')

main = Text(root)
main.pack()

Thread(target=check).start()

root.mainloop()
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Answers with code samples are helpful but please help future readers by including context or explanation. For more on writing good answers: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer.

Answer (score -1):

You should write something like

```
def start(event):
    t = var.get()
    if t == 'something':
       pass

var = StringVar()
e = Entry(master, textvariable=var)
e.pack()
e.bind(bind('<Return>',start)
```

Comment: text widgets don't support the `textvariable` option. And if they were using an Entry widget, you don't need a `StringVar`, the `get()` method works fine on the widget itself.